# Need to display notification message to CMS authors if image uploaded is greater than specified size

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

I am trying to show notification message while uploading asset in magnolia author CMS if the image size exceeded. Whenever user will upload an image then it will need to check the size of the image  and show notification accordingly  but it wont restrict the user to upload the image even though size got exceeded. I just want to show popup/ alert while uploading the image not fully restrict it. So is it possible to do this ?

I am new to Magnolia so don't have much idea how to proceed on this. Can someone help me on the same . Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need to do much on your side but merely configure Magnolia to handle it for you. One can specify a threshold for file size and configure the field to show error messages accordingly.

Those two settings should do the trick for your case:
sizeInterruption, 
maxUploadSize

For more information, please refer to https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/DAM+upload+field

Update:

Since user doesn't want to have the process interrupted, I suggest to extend `info.magnolia.ui.form.field.upload.AbstractUploadField#updateProgress` method. There currently there is a check which asserts if the size is greater than the threshold if yes it displays the notification and returns. What you want is to display the notification but continue.
So simply removing the line `return;` should do the trick for you.

Hope that helps,

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I have tried this it is restricting user to upload file. The requirement is to show simple warning message not to restrict user to upload the file.  One thing I thought of to write custom validator class where I can check the image size which is getting uploaded and then compare with maximum upload size   and show custom warning message. 

I would be helpful if I get to know how to calculate image size . Whenever we upload any asset there something any method which is getting called and calculating the size of the image. Thanks !!

Comment: I'll update the answer with suggestions to start where to look at.